# The relative motion of a charged particle moving through a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, magnetic-fields, charge

When a charged particle moves in a magnetic field,  a force of $F=qv\times B $  is applied on the particle. (Lorentz force)

So lets say that a magnet is sitting on a table, and a charged particle is held on top of it. When we move the particle, it will experiance a force $F=qv\times B $

However, when the particle stays put and the magnet moves, from my knowledge, because the strength of the magnetic field is constant, nothing happens.

How does this even make sense? Shouldn't the same force be applied when the relative motion between them is the same?

Comment: The force will depend on the frame of reference of the observer. If the magnetic field is truly uniform, then this is correct. In reality, a magnet will produce a localized magnetic field, so the charged particle will see a time dependent magnetic field in it's rest frame. This leads to an electromotive force via Faraday's law, which will act on the particle even though $\vec v = 0$. This observation is what led Einstein to develop special relativity in the first place.

Comment: But doesn't the fact that "if there is a uniform magnetic field, and it is moving, no force is applied" make no sense at all?

Comment: In both cases, if the observer is on the magnet, the charged particle will look same to them.

Comment: So shouldn't the force that is applied on the particles look the same to the observer standing on the uniform magnetic field?

Comment: If that's the case, then shouldn't there be some sort of an "absolute zero speed"? (which is of course not true)

Comment: If there is a uniform magnetic field, how can it be "moving"?